# Pandas dataframe replace value on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    limit1  limit2 
a    123     567
b    65      0
c    123     1233
d    0987    0
e    231451  0998
```

I want to create a new frame with the lower limit for each row. Except when there is a 0, in which case the value from the other column is taken.

desired output:

```
    limit1  limit2
a    123     567
b    65      65
c    123     1233
d    0987    0987
e    231451  0998
```

As you can see the 0 on the right are replaced with the value from the corresponding row from the left.

My following code does not work:

```
low_limit = pd.concat([limit1, limit2], join='outer', axis=1)
if limit2 == 0:
    low_limit = limit1
else:
    low_limit.min(axis=1).dropna()
```

the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: @AMC No, it does not

Comment: Isn't it the exact same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where(condition, outcome if condition is True, outcome ifcondition false)`

```
df['limit2']=np.where(df.limit2==0,df.limit1,df.min(1))

    limit1  limit2
a     123     123
b      65      65
c     123     123
d     987     987
e  231451     998
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can do `replace` since `min(NaN, not NaN value)` out put the not null value

```
df.limit2 = df.replace({'limit2' : {0 : np.nan}}).min(axis=1)
df
Out[46]: 
   limit1  limit2
a     123   123.0
b      65    65.0
c     123   123.0
d     987   987.0
e  231451   998.0
```